# What's the meaning of the phrase "take a stand on"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> The object model and relational model are different schemas and as such compromises have to happen. NHibernate makes a very good job in hiding those compromises in most cases, but when it comes to inverse management you the developer need to **take a stand on** what compromise is the right one for your solution. Now you know your options, choose wisely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is another way to say "commit to" or "take a position on."  I'm not sure on this, but it probably comes by a battlefield analogy, where it can be important for symbolic reasons for one side to hold some particular piece of ground in the face of adversity.   For example, in the United States, the famous Martin Luther King Jr. might be described as having "taken a stand" on civil rights issues, because he protested bigotry and segregation despite being at risk for his life and being jailed for his activism.

[image: Liberty]

Pictures make the best examples: A caption for this famous painting of Delacroix's might describe her, Lady Liberty, as "taking a stand" for liberty, the revolution, and France.  You can see how the meaning of the phrase derives from its imagery; note the Lady's body language.

> ...the developer needs to take a stand on what compromise is the right one for your solution.

In the sentence you gave here, the usage is not quite so dramatic as in the above; an adequate replacement would be "make a firm choice" or "take a firm commitment to" whatever solution your text is talking about. The key, in all the various meanings I've given, is the importance of the adjective "firm"; taking a stand, now matter dramatic you want to be, is the opposite of its antonyms "noncommital," "wavering," or "wishy-washy."

Comment: Commitment is a big part of it, but there is a nuance. I would say it is possible for someone to commit to something privately without taking a stand. To "take a stand on" something usually entails a public commitment. It also entails a firm commitment (as you suggested), meaning that the person will effectively maintain or defend his position in an argument over the issue at hand.

Comment: I had a rather [more prosaic example](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091042/quotes?qt0441180) come to mind :)